# How can I insert the quoted price of gold from kitco.com into my excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

kitco.com provides a realtime price quote for gold and other metals. I have a spreadsheet which makes calculations based on the price of gold and would like for this realtime value to automatically be updated on my excel sheet. I tried 'get external data' from a website but that didn't work. any ideas?

EDIT ADDED: Kitco has a gadget called KCAST which displays realtime quotes on the Windows taskbar. I tried capturing those values from the taskbar but that didn't work either. Maybe if Kitco provided an API or feed, it could be done?

Comment: I can suggest a method, but first I need to know which is the exact web page you are interested in.

Comment: @Toc: kitco.com

Comment: After your edit, I think that updating quotation were simpler if you would use Google Docs instead of Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a web query in excel 2003.It does work.
 select the table on the left of their page.

[image]

Then import to the excel range you want. You can either refresh as you want, or setup a macro to handle that pretty easily. This gives you Bid and Ask prices which import into two separate fields so you should be able to use either as your live number.

Comment: actually forgot you can set the refresh rate in the data range properties after you insert the web query. Seems like the lowest refresh rate is every minute

Answer (score 6):

If you can program in Visual Basic for Applications, the macro language of Excel, you will want to [use the ActiveX XMLHttpRequest object](http://scriptorium.serve-it.nl/view.php?sid=40) provided by Internet Explorer to access arbitrary URLs.

Then, although it is not the strictly "correct" way of doing it, you can [create a regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html) to extract the gold price from the web page's source code. Finally, update the correct cell.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Google Docs Import function below.

Note that the table number may change; find the correct table number by searching page source after finding the table data your want (i.e. gold spot).  Table numbers are shown in the search results of find in the Chrome browser (i.e. 22 of 24 `</table>` using the CTRL-F find function.

```
=ImportHtml("http://www.kitco.com/market/"; "table";20)
```

Comment: I dont understand. My app is written with Microsoft Excel and Access. Why Google Docs, and not Excel importing it directly?.. or you mean from GDocs to Excel, explain.

Answer (score 0):

The kitco website recently changed format and will likely in the future, but as of today (31 Jan 2024), the following works in Google sheets for the live bid price of gold:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.kitco.com/charts/livegold.html", "//h3[@class='text-4xl font-mulish font-bold leading-normal tracking-[1px] mb-[3px]']"
```

and here's for silver:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.kitco.com/charts/livesilver.html", "//h3[@class='text-4xl font-mulish font-bold leading-normal tracking-[1px] mb-[3px]']")
```